Can not find the resoning of the following output
let bytes = new Uint16Array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
let view = new DataView(bytes.buffer, bytes.byteOffset, bytes.byteLength);
let int = view.getUint32(0);   // Read big-endian unsigned int from byte 0
console.log(1, int);
int = view.getUint32(4, false); // Next int is also big-endian
console.log(2, int);
int = view.getUint32(8, true); // Next int is little-endian and unsigned
console.log(3, int);
view.setUint32(8, int, false); // Write it back in big-endian format
int = view.getUint32(8, false);
console.log(4, int);

Output:
1 256,
2 33555200,
3 327684,
4 327684
I have changed all the output from signed to unsigned but could not understand the result.
In the first case the first 4 byte in big-endian it is expected as 00 00 00 01 in binary then why 256?


In the first case the first 4 byte in big-endian it is expected as 00 00 00 01

This is platform dependent. As Mozilla Contributors write on Uint16Array

The Uint16Array typed array represents an array of 16-bit unsigned integers in the platform byte order.

So the bytes may be stored in this order: 00 00 01 00 02 00 03 00, which corresponds to little-endian storing of 16-bit values (2 bytes). Little-endian is the most common.
Then, when reading the first 4 bytes in big-endian, the one-but-last byte thus represents multiples of 256.
This explains the first two outputs you get:
00 00 01 00 02 00 03 00
----------- ----------- 
     ↓           ↓
   0x100     0x2000300
    256      33555200


Nicely explained.
